# I can't use the mobile app or change my password. How do I fix this?

Tags: support, ios-app, login

I downloaded the mobile app for SE on my iPad today.  The first thing it asks me to do is sign in.  I tried to sign in with Google and used my GMail address.  I never even got asked for a password, it rejected me with "Request failed" and "Could not peform this request with your account.  Please try logging back in.  If this persists, let us know on meta."

So, wondering what was going on, I opened Safari and went to SE and logged in - with my Google ID.  It worked.  I went back to the app and tried again.  Same issue.  So I looked at my profile page and, while there, added a new email login.  Here's my profile info for logins with identifying info redacted:

[image: Profile page with logins]

Note it does see my Google ID.  By the time I got to this page (on my home computer) it was hours after I had logged in, but the time that login was last used was correct.  So SE does recognize my Google login, at least through the website, even if it doesn't on the mobile app.

While here I thought I'd try to update my OpenID login.  Maybe the app would let me use that.  Note there is no link to change the password there.  I went to the [OpenID website](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) to try to update my password there.  It won't recognize my ID.  (I tried several IDs I might have used, just in case, but the one given on email from OpenID (7 years ago) is not even recognized by OpenID, so I can't get the password or change it.  (I tried a few extra "possible" OpenID names, so now it won't accept attempts from my IP address.)

Please also note that I have 2 IDs at the end of the list of IDs that are email addresses, but there is no way to change passwords for these logins.

The bottom line is I want to do the following:

1. Get my IP unblocked from OpenID
2. Verify my OpenID is still working or is dead.
3. If my OpenID is still working, I want to change the password.
4. Be able to login to the mobile app with my Google ID or find out why I can't.
5. Be able to change passwords or at least properly use the last 2 IDs on the settings page that apparently have no associated passwords.

Comment: Just fyi, if an email is listed under Other then it is only a verified email that can be used for email notifications. If you want to set it up as a credential, simply use the "add more logins" button directly below that list, and type in that email and a password, and it will set it up as a credential. It should then move up under a "Stack Exchange" section. -- I wouldn't know why the iOS app isn't accepting your Google login though.

Comment: Thank yo, @animuson!  That gives me a work-around that I can use for now.  I'm still hoping, though, someone can tell me how to get the Google ID working or why it doesn't on the app.